# How to use LOOP AT itab INTO <fieldsymbol>

Tags: syntax-error, abap

As I rarely loop into a field symbol, I often forget to use `ASSIGNING` instead of `INTO` which will promptly cause an abend. Is there a valid use of `INTO` with `<fieldsymbol>` or is this something that the syntax checker really ought to catch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is valid when `<fieldsymbol>` was previously assigned to a structure which has the type of the lines of the table you loop over.

Answer (score 5):

`LOOP...INTO` is perfectly valid but it will work differently.  `LOOP...INTO` transports the values to the structure provided but `ASSIGNING` assigns the field symbol to the actual table rows.

The only difference is if you are going to change the table contents.  See the following:

```
* Changes all entries in the CARRID column of lt_flights to 50.
LOOP AT lt_flights ASSIGNING <flight>.
  <flight>-carrid = 50.
ENDLOOP.

* Does not change the entries in lt_flights (MODIFY...FROM would be required).
ASSIGN <flight> TO ls_flight.
LOOP AT lt_flights INTO <flight>.
  <flight>-carrid = 50.
ENDLOOP.
```

`LOOP...INTO` with a field symbol would be useless unless you had some kind of dynamic programming requirement.

Answer (score 2):

It is a perfectly valid statement:

```
APPEND INITIAL LINE TO lt_foo ASSIGNING <ls_foo>.
READ TABLE lt_bar INTO <ls_foo> INDEX 1.
```

A field symbol just takes the place of a variable - at almost any point - so the syntax check can't flag this as invalid. It might issue a warning, though...